# Wiring package exceptions in Fuse/Karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, fuseesb

In many projects, I have came across this exception. What could be the reason for this exception ?

According to my knowledge, it can be because of inconsistent version usage. What could be the other possible scenarios ?

Is this because of the Camel version we are using in the project ?Please help.

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.test.div.soa.module-notify[324]: Unable to resolve 324.0: missing requirement [324.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel)(version>=2.11.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
                at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4155)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
                at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2055)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
                at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.0.3.redhat-60024.jar:]
                at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1247)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
                at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1219)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
                at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:508)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]
                at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:291)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.3.11.redhat-60024]

Regards
Guru

Comment: What is your camel version? And can you please paste the maven `dependency` from your pom for your camel dependencies?

Comment: Yes. It was camel version issue. Got resolved after changing the version as per the claus comment below. Thanks Steve

Comment: Great! I'm also "looking forward to" some camel 2.11 / 2.12 features (controlBus ftw!) but we haven't upgraded JBoss Fuse just yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bundle, which I assume is installed by copying it to the deploy directory of the ESB instead of using the more appropriate way of using osgi:install command.

Anyway your bundle requires Camel 2.11, and the ESB comes out of the box with Camel 2.10. So change your bundle to use Camel 2.10 which is shipped with the ESB.